# Swift String addingPercentEncoding not working for all special characters

Tags: ios, swift, url-encoding

This is the string which is further passed as url parameter :

```
pass@#$%&*?123
```

I am using this for encoding the characters :

```
password.text?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)
```

This gives me :

```
pass@%23$%25&*?123
```

Thus not all characters are encoded using this.
I also tried with **urlQueryAllowed**, **urlPasswordAllowed** and other values, but they don't encode all the characters (if you want, I can share the encoded values).
This is the desired string :

```
pass%40%23%24%25%26*%3F123
```

What should be used here ?

Comment: Please edit the question as to, what i the desired output you want

Comment: try .urlHostAllowed

Comment: @MahipalSingh : That didn't work as well.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "url parameter". You might clarify what you mean. Please take a look at `URLComponents`, which likely will do the job.